# Cross product as result of projections

Tags: linear-algebra, cross-product

The cross product between two vectors in $\Bbb{R}^3$ (call them **a** and **b**) is denoted **a** $\times$ **b** and the result is a vector in $\Bbb{R}^3$ orthogonal to the first two. There are a variety of ways of computing this resultant vector. One way in particular is known from the symbolic determinant involving **i j k** and the entries of **a** and **b**.

I recall a professor awhile back trying to explain why **a** $\times$ **b** can be seen from this by appealing to the notion of finding the projection of the parallelogram with sides **a** and **b** onto the xy, xz and yz planes (imagine **a** and **b** floating in 3-space, so we're finding the projection of **a** and **b** onto these planes and finding the new area of the parallelogram after this projection). The goal was to show that the factor scaling the **i**  component of **a** $\times$ **b** was the area of the parallelogram formed by **a** and **b** after being projected onto the yz plane, and similarly for the **j** component being scaled by the area of the projected parallelogram of **a** and **b** in the xz plane and the **k** component from the xy plane.

The explanation seemed straightforward at the time, but in trying to remember it I'm a little lost. Is anyone familiar with this notion of finding the areas under projection and these areas being the magnitudes of the **i j** and **k** components of **a** $\times$ **b**?

I hope that isn't too vague. I know that we had an explanation for the sign change of the **j** component as well being connected to these smashed projections but I don't recall how that worked either.

Comment: The monolith of words was a little intimidating, so I went ahead and used things called *linebreaks* to make it more likely that readers would read it all. Whitespace really does miracles for making text more readable!

Comment: I made an attempt to answer this here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/596158/cross-products

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The magnitude of the cross-product $\|\mathbf{a}\times \mathbf{b}\|$ gives the area of the parallelogram formed by vectors $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ as edges. I do not know exactly what your professor is talking about so I will take a guess here.

From the [Cauchy-Binet Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Binet_formula), the area of the parallelogram is related to the areas of the projections of the parallelogram onto the $xy,\ xz$ and $yz$ planes. This is a higher dimension analogue of the familiar Pythagorean theorem. If we denote $\|\mathbf{a}\times \mathbf{b}\|_{xy}$ to be the area of the projection onto the $xy$-plane, then the areas are related as
$$\|\mathbf{a}\times \mathbf{b}\|^2 = \|\mathbf{a}\times \mathbf{b}\|_{xy}^2 + \|\mathbf{a}\times \mathbf{b}\|_{xz}^2 + \|\mathbf{a}\times \mathbf{b}\|_{yz}^2$$
Now each projection is given by a smaller determinant. The $xy$ projection for example is given by
$$\|\mathbf{a}\times \mathbf{b}\|^2_{xy} = \begin{vmatrix}a_1^2 + a_2^2 & a_1b_1 + a_2b_2 \\ a_1b_1 + a_2b_2 & b_1^2 + b_2^2\end{vmatrix}$$
where $a_i$ and $b_i$ are the respective components of $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$. This is evaluated as
$$(a_1^2 + a_2^2)(b_1^2 + b_2^2) - (a_1b_1 + a_2b_2)^2 = a_1^2b_2^2 -2a_1b_1a_2b_2+ a_2^2b_1^2 = (a_1b_2 - a_2b_1)^2$$
This is precisely the (square of the) third component of the cross-product.