# How to tidy up this Cross Product derivation?

Tags: cross-product

Last week I wrote [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1845771/3096).

However, I don't feel it is complete. I make an arbitrary choice of unit vector perpendicular to **u,v**.  But I can't see how to integrate this fact into the derivation.

I would like to complete the line of reasoning, as it motivates the crossproduct from the elementary task of constructing a vector perpendicular to two others.

Can anyone repair the narrative without escalating the complexity?  Or get me to a point of understanding where I can make such a repair.

Here is a copy of the original (the original may change!):

---

There is indeed a geometric interpretation of $\bf{u}\times\bf{v}$ in terms of the areas of the projections of the parallelogram $\bf{P}$ spanned by $\bf{v}$ and $\bf{w}$ onto the coordinate planes.

I'll start from scratch.

> Motivating problem:  We wish to create a vector perpendicular to **u,v**, i.e. construct **w** s.t. $\bf{w}\cdot \bf{u} = \bf{w}\cdot \bf{v} = 0$.

Two equations in 3 unknowns: we can derive **w** as $\lambda(u_2 v_3 - u_3 v_2,$ [3&1], [1&2]$)$.

> So let's ***define*** $\bf{u}\times \bf{v}$ as ($u_2 v_3 - u_3 v_2$, [3&1], [1&2]).

Observe $u_2 v_3 - u_3 v_2$ is just the signed area of the $(u_2, u_3)$, $(v_2,v_3)$ parallelogram. *(2D determinant -- you can work it out with triangles).*  So we can rewrite our definition:

> ***Define*** $\bf{u}\times \bf{v}$ as $(A_{yz}, A_{zx}, A_{xy})$   where $A_{\text{plane}}$ = *signed area of **u,v** parallelogram projected onto that plane*

Notice by symmetry, switching **u** and **v** just changes the sign of $u_p v_q - u_q v_p$, so we have:

> $\bf{u}\times \bf{v} = -\bf{v}\times \bf{u}$

Notice also:

> $\bf{i} \times \bf{j} = \bf{k}$

So we get our 'Right Hand Rule'.

Now it makes sense to ask: "Could we have skipped the algebra?" i.e. arrived at this definition purely from geometric insight. And the answer is yes!

Let **n** be the unit vector perpendicular to **u,v** *using the **Right Hand Rule** to resolve ambiguity*.

We can show that the ratio of the area of the **uv**-parallelogram to it's **yz** projection gives $\bf{n}_x$, similarly for **xz**$\to \bf{n}_y$ and **xy**$\to \bf{n}_z$:

> Here is a simplification that will illustrate this...
>
> Let's say we have y as depth, z going upwards. We have some near-flat plane (so the normal is pointing nearly straight up). Suppose we draw a unit grid on it. Now we are going to drop each point onto the xy-plane so $(x,y,z)\to(x,y,0)$ and calculate the change in area. Furthermore let's say we have rotated things so that our plane's normal vector has depth component = 0.
>
> So alternatively we could set this up by imagining two xy-planes. And rotate one of them slightly around the y-axis, give it a unit grid, and "drop" this grid onto the other (axis-aligned) plane.
>
> We want the area of a projected grid square.
>
> It should be obvious that the depth-component (y) of any point on our plane is unchanged by this projection. And a simple calculation reveals that the x-component is just $cos(\theta)$, where $\theta$ is the angle between the normals, otherwise known as $\bf{k}\cdot \bf{n}=\bf{n}_z$, where $\bf{k}=(0,0,1)$.
>
> So, the xy-area multiplier is $\bf{n}_z$ as required.

Let's write these parallelogram areas using $A$.

So we have: $A_{xy} = A \bf{n}_z$, sim. for y & z.

So $A\bf{n} = (A_{yz}, A_{zx}, A_{xy})$

**(EDIT: Bold rendering incorrectly for $A_{xy}$ in the above line, anyone?)**

So if we ***define*** $\bf{u}\times \bf{v}$ as $(A_{yz}, A_{zx}, A_{xy})$ then we have $\bf{u}\times \bf{v} = A \bf{n}$, i.e. $\bf{u}\times \bf{v}$ is perpendicular to **u,v** and of length $A$.

QED!

Comment: Which part are you not happy with? Choosing $\lambda=1$? The right hand rule? Also, is [Oscar's answer to your other question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/752070/motivation-for-construction-of-cross-product-quaternions/1639497#1639497) on this topic not a good enough motivation for the cross product?

Comment: @Bye_World, yes, essentially that is what I'm unhappy with. And both of those boil down to the same thing, because $\lambda=-1$ would give a left-hand rule. It's just that I have to make an arbitrary choice. Maybe this is connected with the *alternating* property. It just feels like the penny hasn't dropped somewhere.

Comment: @Bye_World, Although his answer is insightful (and I am grateful for it), to me the motivation seems weak and contrived. i.e. We already have the cross product and we are trying to find a motivation. i.e. We start by rummaging around for an operator that meets certain criteria for no good reason!